# Show only matched items in ListBox (C#)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, search, listbox, listboxitem

I write quick search function for searching matched items in ListBox:

```
 for (int i = listBox1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (listBox1.Items[i].ToString().Contains(textBox1.Text))
                {
                    listBox1.SetSelected(i, true);
                }
            }
```

It selects first matched item. How can I **temporarily hide** all other items not matching the search query (inside this ListBox1)?

By the way, ListBox contains only numbers, no text stings.

[Full source code here](https://pastecode.xyz/view/9bef78f2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the SelectionMode property is set for MultiExtended, try moving your "if" condition into the boolean parameter:

```
for (int i = listBox1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  listBox1.SetSelected(i, listBox1.Items[i].ToString().Contains(textBox1.Text));
}
```